# Need to toggle a Boolean in a if else statement

Tags: java

Okay, I need to be able to call a method and toggle a boolean value so that the return is different every time I need to be able to call the method 9 time's and each time switch between returning X, O, X, O, X, O, X, O, X

```
public class XOChecker {
    char rX = 'X';
    char rO = 'O';
    char rXO;
    boolean t = true;

   public char setXO() {

       if (t==true) {

       rXO = rX;

       } else if (t==false) {

       rXO = rO;

       }
       return rXO;
   }  

}
```

Comment: Change t to its logical not (i.e, its inverse), then return rx0:  t = !t; return rx0;  This will leave t properly set for you when you come back into the function.

Comment: You can use `rXO = t ? rX : r0;` instead of `if(){} else if(){}`

Comment: Overengineered, much? :) (r.e. original question)

Answer (score 3):

how about:

```
return (t = !t) ? rO : rX;
//        ^ invert t every time
//                   ^ t changes every time, so the return value changes every time
```

the following code:

```
public class XOChecker {
    char rX = 'X';
    char rO = 'O';
    boolean t = true;

    public char setXO() {
        return (t = !t) ? rX : rO;
    }  

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        XOChecker xo = new XOChecker();
        for (int i = 0; i < 100 ; ++i) {
            System.out.print(xo.setXO());
        }
    }
}
```

outputs:

```
OXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOX
```

Comment: Try that and all I get is x returned every time.

Comment: @BrandonCruz are you sure you wrote `(t = !t)` and not `(t == !t)`?

Comment: Can you show the code that calls the method? I suspect that you create a new object each time.

Comment: Im not on a pc right now but some like this if(ev.getSource()==btnXO[0]) { char XO0; XO0 = checker.setXO(); btnXO[0].setText("" + XO0);........ and their are 8you more else it statements and I just change all the 0 to 1,2,3 and so on

Comment: I get OXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOXOX, as expected.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class XOChecker {

    char xo = 'O';

    public char setXO(){
        xo = (xo=='O')?'X':'O';
        return xo;
    }

}
```

Alternatively: `xo = (char)('X'-xo+'O');`

And finally: `xo^='X'^'O';`

Or shorter:

```
public char setXO(){
    return xo^=23;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
t = !t;
if(t) {
  return rX;
} else {
  return rO;
}
```

BTW, the name of the method is misleading. It should be `getSomething`, not `setSomething`, based on what it does.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your attempt is :

You are not changing value of t, after calling the method. 
Also **else if (t==false)** is equivalent to **else**

You have the change the value of t each time you call the method. Something like :

```
if(t)
{
   t = false;
   return rX;
}
else
{
   t = true;
   return rO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Declare constants as `static final` (or get rid of them completely).
- Declare everything used only internally `private`.
- Unlike other replies, don't do assignment inside expressions.
- Use more meaningful names.

Here goes:

```
public class XOChecker
{
    private static final char REPLY_TRUE = 'X';
    private static final char REPLY_FALSE = 'O';

    private boolean t = true;

    public char toggle()
    {
        final char result = t ? REPLY_TRUE : REPLY_FALSE;
        t = !t;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay this code kinda works, but I have to call the method 2 times to get it to switch back and forth I can only get it to work in the order of the buttons, which won't work for tic tac toe.